# Link Cortana Alert / Notification and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, cortana, cortana-intelligence, cortana-skills-kit

I would like Python to read any Cortana Notification / Alert it receives from my mobile.

Whenever my mobile receive a Message / WhatsApp, it is displayed into windows using Cortana. Now, I and would like to use this content into python, i.e., link Cortana Alert to Python. Lastly, Python would receive the text/content and run some AI scripts.

Tks and have a great day

Comment: is cortona notifications linked to any kind of website? eg. Windows.com when youre logged in?

Comment: Cortana is "channel connector" for botframework. You should use it to monitor a channel for a message - but there is no connector for WhatsApp (and no public api to build one). You could build something to relay push notifications to a channel for Cortana.

Comment: @Stanley, I have Cortana in my Mobile. Whenever I receive any Notification in my mobile, it automatically pops in Windows Cortana.

Comment: Thats what i thought. Take a look at my answer

Comment: @Stanley, do you have any idea someone could develop it for me for a reasonable price? Seems to be much higher level than I am capable. Tks

Comment: @Ricardo Depends what price you find reasonable, python is very easy to learn and i would suggest you take this on as a challenge, if you have no interest in programming, you could check out https://www.freelancer.com/ or similar sites

Comment: @Ricardo eventually you could try to explain what you'd like and i will try to make it for you for free

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> You would need a module named pywin32
>   `https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/`